# Downloading a file on Windows phone using PhoneGap

Tags: windows, file, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins

With the help of this link 'https://gist.github.com/nathanpc/2464060' I have written code to download a file in PhoneGap. I tried it on Android phone and it works perfectly. 
But on Windows phone, It says that it has downloaded and the path is -- //xyz/SIFA.pdf.

To look at the file system on Windows phone I have downloaded an app called 'Files' using which I looked up on the phone but I could not find any folder xyz nor the file.

I also connected the Windows phone to my PC and had a look but could not find the folder nor the pdf

Could you suggest what I am doing wrong in the code or if I am not looking for the file in the right way.

Thanks for your help in advance

Here is my code to download file in PhoneGap.
I have added alerts to indicate the progress.

```
var folderName = 'xyz';
var fileName;

var downloadFileOne = function (URL) {
//step to request a file system 
alert("step one");
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);
alert("step two");
function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    alert("step three");
    var download_link = encodeURI(URL);
    alert("step four - " + download_link);
    fileName = download_link.substr(download_link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //Get filename of URL
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
    directoryEntry.getDirectory(folderName, {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
    alert("step five");
    var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
    var fp = fileSystem.root.toNativeURL(); // Returns Fullpath of local directory

    fp = fp + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
    // download function call
    filetransfer(download_link, fp);
}

function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
    // Directory created successfuly
    alert("directory created successfully");
}

function onDirectoryFail(error) {
    //Error while creating directory
    alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);

}

function fileSystemFail(evt) {
    //Unable to access file system
    alert(evt.target.error.code);
}
}

function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
alert("step six - file transfer method");
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
// File download function with URL and local path
fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
    function (entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function (error) {
        //Download abort errors or download failed errors
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
    }
);
}
```

Comment: you may need to make sure you are following windows phone file path structure: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#windows-file-system-layout

Comment: Hi Dawson, thank you for that, I have never worked with files on Windows, could you guide me on what changes you think I need to do in the code for it to work on Windows phone. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any suggestions guys?